# Медиа плеер с выбором стримера

Tags: html, css

Чуть ниже представлена картинка на примере которой я буду объяснять что я хочу и хочу услышать ваши советы по тому как это можно реализовать.

В  находится фрейм с прямой трансляцией с Twitch

(Красным выделена действующая кнопка)

(Кнопка 1 будет активирована по умолчанию)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на кнопку 2, фрейм заменяется трансляцией другого стримера(Соответственно при нажатии на Кпопки 3,4 фреймы так же меняются)

Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать, потому что идей вообще никаких нет, пытался найти что-то подобное в гугле и т.д, ничего не нашёл.

Comment: Айфреймы с Твича автоматически сразу начинают транслироваться, или для трансляции на таком фрейме нужно нажать, чтобы пошёл поток видео?

Comment: Они воспроизводятся сами, но вроде можно autoplay=false/true(autoplay=0/1) настроить чтобы по клику воспроизводилось